# Filter member properties in Query Designer using MDX

Tags: reporting-services, mdx, ssrs-2012, ssrs-expression, query-designer

**How can I filter two member properties using MDX?**

[image]

Currently I have the following solution. It works but I'm sure an `MDX` query would be much more efficient.

The Dataset in Query Designer has the following `MDX` to include the member properties as fields:

```
DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME, [Store].[Store].[Closed Date],[Store].[Store].[Opening Date]
```

I am using two filters in the Dataset Properties with the following expressions:

```
    =Cint(Fields!Opening_Date.Value) 
    < 
    =Cint(Format(Today(), "yyyyMMdd"))
```

and

```
    =Cint(Fields!Closed_Date.Value) 
    >
    =Cint(Format(Today(), "yyyyMMdd"))
```

Comment: What is the issue you are facing? At a glance I see you want to get the rows where `Closed_Date` is greater than today date, is it right for your logic?

Comment: can you please add some mdx that you have already tried

Comment: @alejandro zuleta: Exaclty, it is running quite slow and I would like to (if possible) add this filter into an MDX query instead.

Comment: @whytheq: I have tried using the filter function, however it did not return any rows. I will get back to you with some code.

Comment: @krynil - did you get a chance to test out my approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that using a filter was the best way to solve this:

```
filter(
  [Store].[Store].members, [Store].[Store].Properties( "Opening Date" ) < Format(Now(),'yyyyMMdd') 
  and [Store].[Store].Properties( "Closed Date" ) > Format(Now(),'yyyyMMdd'))
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I doubt performance of the below would be satisfactory, but you can give it a shot.

```
SELECT SomeDim.SomeHIerarchy.MEMBER 
HAVING 
Val(SomeDim.SomeHIerarchy.CURRENTMEMBER.Properties("Opening Date")) <  Format(now(), "dd-MM-yyyy")
Val(SomeDim.SomeHIerarchy.CURRENTMEMBER.Properties("Closing Date")) > Format(now(), "dd-MM-yyyy")
ON 1,
Measures.Foo on 0
FROM [Your Cube]
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try this out :)

Comment: I managed to solve the issue by using a filter in MDX. Your code definitely helped, so thank you!